# Nested for loops in tpl returning one value

Tags: php, loops, foreach, task-parallel-library

I have 2 arrays to loop through, one holding `$int` and the other `$string`. I want to return both `$int` and `$string` but when I nest to loops in my tpl file it only returns `$int`.

Code:

```
{foreach from=$array.subarray1 item="int"}
  {foreach from=$array.subarray2 item="string"}
    {$string}: {$int}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

I looked at the smarty documentation and I see [one case of a nested loop](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) but when I apply it to my code it doesn't work - this could totally be user error though.. I'm not sure as my experience with working tpl's is limited.

Additional question for my edification: I can get it to work in PHP, not in smarty; should I even be trying to do this in smarty or let PHP do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do from your description isn't incredibly clear, but it sounds like you have two enumerated arrays, where one has the desired key and the other has the desired value. If this is what you are after, you don't need a nested loop. You need to insure that the keys for both arrays equate to the same element, and then do a single loop, using the same key for both arrays to access the correct result.

```
{foreach from=$array.subarray1 item="int" key="key"}
    {$array.subarray2[$key]}: {$int}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works splendidly and my face thanks you (it has been desk-slamming a lot)